# Merging two tables with Spring Boot JPA efficiently

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, rdbms

I have two tables with some similar fields that are filled asynchronously from two different APIs. In each table there is a company ID and some other fields. At the end of each day I want to merge the last data of each company from each table.

I've written the following code:

```
if (cmpID == null)
        cmpID = readCompanyTable();


    int pageSize = 1;

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = emn.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<LegalEntity> criteriaQueryLegal = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(LegalEntity.class);
    Root<LegalEntity> rootLegal = criteriaQueryLegal.from(LegalEntity.class);
    criteriaQueryLegal = criteriaQueryLegal.select(rootLegal);
    criteriaQueryLegal.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(rootLegal.get("timeStamp")));


    CriteriaQuery<PriceRealTimeEntity> criteriaQueryPrice = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PriceRealTimeEntity.class);
    Root<PriceRealTimeEntity> rootPrice = criteriaQueryPrice.from(PriceRealTimeEntity.class);
    criteriaQueryPrice = criteriaQueryPrice.select(rootPrice);
    criteriaQueryPrice.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(rootPrice.get("dateTime")));


    ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list = getCompanyID();

    for (Long com_id : list) {


        Predicate predicateLegal = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootLegal.get("companyID"), com_id);
        criteriaQueryLegal.where(predicateLegal);

        Predicate predicatePrice = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootPrice.get("companyID"), com_id);
        criteriaQueryPrice.where(predicatePrice);

        TypedQuery<LegalEntity> typedQueryLegal = emn.createQuery(criteriaQueryLegal);
        typedQueryLegal.setFirstResult(0);
        typedQueryLegal.setMaxResults(pageSize);

        TypedQuery<PriceRealTimeEntity> typedQueryPrice = emn.createQuery(criteriaQueryPrice);
        typedQueryPrice.setFirstResult(0);
        typedQueryPrice.setMaxResults(pageSize);

        List<LegalEntity> resultsLegal = typedQueryLegal.getResultList();
        List<PriceRealTimeEntity> resultsPrice = typedQueryPrice.getResultList();
        if ( (resultsLegal.isEmpty()) || (resultsPrice.isEmpty()))
            continue;
        try {
        DailyEntity den = new DailyEntity(resultsPrice.get(0), resultsLegal.get(0),
                cmpID.get(Long.valueOf(com_id)).doubleValue(),  addr_data.get(1));
        drep2.save(den);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

I first get the list of company IDs from a table. The create parallel queries and merge data. I know this method is very intuitive and trivial and I am looking for a better solution. This method is very very slow.

Another note: 
I measured the running duration of each code block. This part:

```
        List<LegalEntity> resultsLegal = typedQueryLegal.getResultList();
        List<PriceRealTimeEntity> resultsPrice = typedQueryPrice.getResultList();
```

takes about 0.5 second to run. This is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of JPA Batch execution to improve your performance.

Please refer [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) for an example of doing the same.